# Where does GoogleCreativeContainerClass come from?

Tags: frontend, internet-explorer-9, google-tag-manager, google-people-api

We are having an issue with the following div been injected into our site:

```html
<div class="GoogleCreativeContainerClass" id="gcc_*****" data-creative-load-listener="">
```

It doesn't seem to break anything apart from ie9. It is getting injected in the middle of an SVG sprite sheet and breaking the SVGs.

I believe it's coming from GTM but we have 300 scripts loaded in via GTM!

Comment: Just having the error is not helping in debugging the whole code. Please think in creating a StackBlitz or JSFiddle or something else with the code that people can debug and/or analyze.

Comment: When using some API or plug-ins, we need to follow their syntax, it could according to the property or class name to inject some html elements, please check your code and the Google Api syntax, perhaps you are using the same syntax or class name. If you can post enough code to reproduce the problem, it might be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you resolve this already, however, and just in case, this is coming from any GTM tag which is displaying ads on your web site.

GTM is generating a list of `data-dcm` atributes that are used during the ad-render for each ad-placement you have configured.

The only way to avoid this is removing any specific ads that are displayed at your web site, when the browser is `IE9` as you mentioned.